# Disabling tooltip for certain cells

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, tooltip

I have one gridview in my windows form. Now i'm showing custom tooltip using the following code,

```
private void Audit_Dg_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)


{
          if (e.ColumnIndex == 7 || e.ColumnIndex == 8 || e.ColumnIndex == 10 || e.ColumnIndex == 11 && e.RowIndex >= 0)
          {           
              DataGridViewCell cell = this.Audit_Dg.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];

          cell.ToolTipText = "Click Here To View The Message";


      }
}
```

it showing my message for those cells satisfying my condition and the cell content for all those doesn't satisfying my condition. is there any way to remove that tool-tips from my grid-view and show only my custom tool-tip?
if there any way,please help me...

Comment: what about adding an `else` statement after your if?
`else cell.ToolTipText = string.Empty`

Comment: i tried by adding one ele case with cell.ToolTipText=null,but it won't work for me.

Comment: i tried this also,but no changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `DataGridView` control does not support this. Its [ShowCellToolTips](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.showcelltooltips.aspx) property can only be used to disable tooltips globally. The cases where a tooltip is displayed are documented as:

> - The value of the `DataSource` property is not `null` or the value of the `VirtualMode` property is `true`, and a handler for the
>     `CellToolTipTextNeeded` event sets the
>     `DataGridViewCellToolTipTextNeededEventArgs.ToolTipText` property to a
>     value other than `String.Empty`.
> - The `ToolTipText` property of the cell has a value other than `String.Empty`. Setting this property has no effect when there is a
>     `CellToolTipTextNeeded` event handler because getting the value of the
>     property automatically raises the event and returns the ToolTip text
>     specified in the event handler.
> - The cell value is truncated in the cell display. When the value of the cell `ToolTipText` property value is `String.Empty`, the full
>     value of the truncated cell value is displayed in the ToolTip.

As you can see, there is no way to avoid the third case: If `ShowCellToolTips` is `true` and the value of a cell is truncated, a tooltip containing the full value *will* be displayed.

Comment: Not with a `DataGridView`, no, unless you can ensure there is no truncated cell content.

Comment: What is this truncated cell content?

Comment: Cells that cannot display their whole content, because the content is wider than the cell. Tooltips are automatically displayed in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the previous answer, the default tooltip is shown when a tooltip is not set and the column is not wide enough to display the cell text. The default tooltip can be avoided by making the column wide enough to display the text or by hooking up a CellFormatting-event and providing a text that fits the column, e.g.

```
private void grd_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
  switch (e.ColumnIndex)
  {
    case 7:
    case 8:
      e.Value = string.Empty;
      e.FormattingApplied = true;
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: e.Value = string.Empty was enough for me.