# DataGridViewTextBoxCell is showing false on hovering which is bound to boolean value. How can i hide it?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

[image]

I have a DataGridView in my winform. To it's datasource i am assigning a List which has one boolean property.
This boolean property is bound to the column in grid which is of type DataGridViewTextBoxCell. This cell is empty but on hovering it's showing "False". Is there anyway to hide it?
Please refer the image above.

Comment: HIde the tooltip or hide the column?

Comment: actually tooltip is empty string. still it is showing false - default value of the bound boolean property.
Please consider that i can't hide the column for now.

Comment: Have you tried `dataGridView.ShowCellToolTips = false`?

Comment: dataGridView.ShowCellToolTips = false actually will disable the tooltips for all the columns in the Grid. I want to do it for one column only.

Comment: Why don't you use a `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn`? What is the use of a boolean value in a Text column?

Comment: Anyway, If that value is ignored, you could use the CellFormatting event and: if `(e.ColumnIndex == 0) { e.Value = string.Empty; e.FormattingApplied = true; }`. This won't show any tooltip.

Answer (score 1):

Because I can't comment, i'm posting this link here.

Check this link [Disabling tooltip for certain cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12854293/disabling-tooltip-for-certain-cells)

But short answer, its not possible.

Maybe increase the column or don't use a boolean.

**Edit:**
You can also try this, but is far from perfect.. Sometimes its still showing and sometimes is hiding the ones that was suposed to show.

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellMouseMove(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex >= 0)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
                dataGridView1.ShowCellToolTips = false;
            else
                dataGridView1.ShowCellToolTips = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Guys,
I found that there is no way I can hide the tooltip in my current scenario, either I would have to let go off the DataGridViewTextBoxCell type for the column or increase the width of the cell to enough size which will hide the tooltip.
As a temporary fix, I have increased the width of the cell which is bigger than the size of the text which was showing as tooltip and it is working.
Thanks, everyone for their time.